# python finding sets with shared elements

Tags: python, duplicates, set

My data is a set of frozenset, for example,

```
data = set([frozenset([1,2,3,4]), frozenset([3,4,5,6,7,8]), frozenset([100,200]), frozenset([1,1000, 2000])])
```

and the intended result is the set of frozenset with duplicate elements, i.e.,

```
result = set([frozenset([1,2,3,4]), frozenset([3,4,5,6,7,8]),  frozenset([1,1000, 2000])])
```

Here `frozenset([100,200])` is removed because it does not share any elements with other frozensets. What is an efficient way to implement this?

Comment: Why are you using `frozenset`s here? Their use cases are pretty rare I find

Comment: Each frozenset represents a ring in a graph and later I need to check for ring matches and ring findings. Thus I keep sets of rings in set, and then each ring has to be frozenset for hashing purposes. Do you have other suggestions for the data organization?

Comment: Ah, good, that actually does sound like a valid use case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a `dict` of set elements to counts of how many times they're found, then drop any `frozenset` where the count of all its elements is 1. `collections.Counter` would be handy for this.

This has the advantage of being `O(n)` where `n` is the total number of elements across all sets.

```
from collections import Counter

data = set([frozenset([1,2,3,4]), frozenset([3,4,5,6,7,8]), frozenset([100,200]), frozenset([1,1000, 2000])])
counts = Counter(elt for fs in data for elt in fs)
result = {fs for fs in data if any(counts[elt] > 1 for elt in fs)}

# {frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4}), frozenset({1000, 1, 2000}), frozenset({3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8})}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a set comprehension with a check like that (for each item, check if it has common elements with at least 1 other element):

```
data = set([frozenset([1,2,3,4]), frozenset([3,4,5,6,7,8]), frozenset([100,200]), frozenset([1,1000, 2000])])

new_data = {x for x in data if any(not x.isdisjoint(y) for y in data if y!=x)}

print(new_data)
```

result:

```
{frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4}), frozenset({3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}), frozenset({1000, 1, 2000})}
```

There could be more efficient solutions, but at least the `disjoint` part is handled by efficient `set` routines

Answer (score 0):

This is my version, it does not have any particular advantage, but you may find it more readable.

```
data = set([frozenset([1,2,3,4]), frozenset([3,4,5,6,7,8]), frozenset([100,200]), frozenset([1,1000, 2000])])
result = set()

for item in data:
    for element in item:
        for other_item in data:
            if item != other_item and item not in result:
                if element in other_item:
                    result.add(item)
                    break
>>>print(result)
>>>{frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4}), frozenset({1000, 1, 2000}), frozenset({3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8})}
```